# Is it a good idea to use svn and check diff in command line in Mac OSX?

Tags: svn, macos, command-line, file-comparison

I used to use svn with TortoiseSVN in Windows.
And I always compared every file I modified to the old ones with WinMerge after every time I modified them.

But I couldn't find a svn client like TortiseSVN and a directory/file comparison tool like WinMerge in mac.

So unfortunately, I have to use svn in command line.
And I have to use `svn diff` command and check differences on the terminal screen.

I'm very afraid I will make more mistakes and bugs if I use command line instead of GUI.
Is it good I a idea to use command line instead of GUI?

And is it normal to compare every file I modified to the old ones with WinMerge after every time I modified them?
Or am i worrying too much?
Is there a application like WinMerge easily and quickly to compare files in 2 directories in mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it good I a idea to use command line instead of GUI?

Yes.

> And is it normal to compare every file I modified to the old ones with WinMerge after every time I modified them?

Yes.

Also.  Buy this: http://www.syncrosvnclient.com/

Comment: @S.Lott Thanks for your answer. Could you tell me the reasons why it is a good idea? syncrosvn looks nice, thanks.

Comment: "I'm very afraid I will make more mistakes and bugs if I use command line instead of GUI."  This is simply silliness.  Many programmers write lots and lots of code without GUI's.  A GUI is not *essential*; it does not *prevent* any problems.

Comment: @S.Lott Ok. I want to be able to write codes without GUI, too. Are you using svn in command line?

Answer (score 2):

Typically I work with the IDE like Eclipse with build-in svn support. But of course you can use the commandline client! But you need not. I also tried [svnX](http://code.google.com/p/svnx/) on Mac OS X as an open source svn GUI.

By the way: No I do not diff all files before commit, I run all tests!

Answer (score 1):

I'm in some way the oposite of you: In my daily work I use the build-in SVN support of Eclipse. But if I have to do more than trivial tasks (like a simple commit or update) I switch to the command line.

I do this because I never took the time to find out what's exactly happening if I click on this or that button in GUI-tools. But I do know exactly what happening on the command line.

Would I make more mistakes if I would use a GUI-tool instead of the command line? Probably not, once I tried out and learned the functions of all buttons.

> Is there a application like WinMerge easily and quickly to compare files in 2 directories in mac?

Well, there's `diff` …

But if you only want to find out which files were modified, use `svn status` (or short: `svn st`). This gives you a list of all files in the current directory, that are modified, conflicted, added or deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You are worrying too much. Look at it as a learning opportunity, learning how to use the SVN commandline tools. And others here can chime in with GUI SVN tools for Mac.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the gui stuff, I'd steer you towards an IDE (IntelliJ IDEA or eclipse).
You'll get integration with svn at least as good as you had with tortoise.

What are you currently using for an editor?   What language(s) do you primarily work with?

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I will try `command line` but I wanna also try `IDE`.
But I am also not good at IDE because IDE is very complicated for me.
I use just text editor instead of IDE.
I'm using a editor called `mi` ( http://www.mimikaki.net/en/ ) in `mac` for the last few weeks.
I think it's good editor but I bought and started my first `mac` last month.
So I'm not sure it is the best editor for me.
(In `windows`, I used `EmEditor` ( http://www.emeditor.com/ ).)

Comment: I work with `javascript`, `html`, `ruby`(I began to learn ruby from yesterday to save logs of my javascript application), and I'm gonna create iPhone/iPodTouch applications(Objective-c?, I don't know what languages I have to use to do that.).